# How to install flat mount road disc brake calipers on IS mount bike?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, road

I have custom MTB frame and I bought a pair of Shimano Hydraulic road shifters.
They have on Shimano BR-RS505 Road Hydraulic Brake Calipers Flat Mount when instead my frame takes standard IS 51 mount (+adapter of course for it).

What kind of adapter should I use?
I have noticed that this kind of calipers use a front adapter mount and it might work on the back too...

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: As far as i know there is not an adapter at this point to use a flat mount caliper on a post mount frame they are not backwards compatible in that sense. There are adapters to use post mount brakes on a flat mount frame but not the other way around. At least not yet that i have seen.

Comment: I edited the title because this question pertains equally to all flat mount road calipers.

Comment: @PaoloGoatspeed you can use any Shimano post-mount calipers and IS adapter instead of BR-RS505. I suppose even older IS calipers might work OK.

Comment: Hi guys,
so I am going to use the standard flat adapter they suggest to use on the front brake/fork, and then add to it a normal post mount IS adapter,
then I will understand if it does the job, depending on the angle it will get.

Comment: @NateWengert , right the market hasn't got much to use these brakes yet, and wat available is expensive. I standard flat mount is around 20/30 euro, can't believe it.

Comment: @NathanKnutson , well done by editing the title, if it makes it clearer.

Comment: @Klaster_1 that's the plan if the adapter doesn't work, change the caliper to a standard mtb one. I will see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now there is no commercial product you can buy to make this possible. An adapter that did this would be awkward to design because the flat mount caliper, in its native spatial position relative to the rotor and stay/blade, is trying to occupy some of the same space as the IS tabs. I believe it's physically possible but it would have to resort to being bulky and positioning the caliper quite far away along the rotor from where the tabs sit, which is a very negative design trade-off. It may even raise questions about how much leverage the tabs or mounting bolts can handle.

Comment: I don't have any adapter top test it, but I will soon try one.
I understand your point but I think that the position and caliper shape is less awkward that it looks.
Definitely is bulky, that's why they moved it to the inside of the stays.

Comment: Yes, to answer to your point: the 2 different types of caliper occupy and "bite" different areas and shapes of the rotor I think...but I will check

Answer (score 3):

Just an update on this topic:
I have now checked what is available on the market and realised (as we have discussed previously here) that the easiest way to achieve my goal is changing the calipers to post mount.
I am not sure if I could build an adapter to use flat mount calipers on post mount frames, but this would mean putting the caliper farther from the rotor, affecting the positioning of it.
There might be as well another problem, that the natural curve of the rotor would not fit on a flat mount caliper used as post mount.
I hope this is useful (for somebody) and please let me know if you have any other question.
Paolo

Answer (score 3):

AS Solutions in Canada now sell an adapter for IS directly to flat mount, with caveats around what size rotors can be used and whether your frame has clearance.

From their site:

> Rear IS mount (Frame): This adapter will only work with 160 mm.
> rotors. Front IS mount (Fork): This adapter will only work with 180
> mm. rotors.
>
> This will not be compatible with all IS mount frames and forks. The
> caliper and adapter extend out from the mounting surface.  Clearance
> between the mounting holes is required.

They do provide a template so you can print out and test with frame/fork

https://www.assolutions.ca/shop/adapters/flat-mount-adapter-for-is-frame/

Comment: Welcome to the site. I see this is new since the other answer mentioning AS Solutions and is specific to the IS mounts. Can you [edit] in what the caveats are? That would be enlightening. A picture of the mount would also be an interesting inclusion.

Comment: Likewise - what are the pros and cons of this solution?  You can [edit] them into your answer.  Welcome to SE - good first start btw.

Comment: At this point even Shimano made quite a few adapters... Price is around 20 euro. At the time when this post was made there were not a lot of options and often changing the calipers was the best one...

Comment: @PaoloGoatspeed Do you have any part numbers? I've been unable to find an IS frame / flat mount caliper adapter from Shimano

Comment: Are you sure you want to buy an adapter? at this point the best I have done over the years has been changing the callipers to normal deore mtb ones.

Comment: this post is from 2017 and I have had the same callipers ever since, and they work perfect. I have actually upgraded my levers from Tiagra to GRX and still working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

A.S.Solutions [makes](https://www.assolutions.ca/shop/adapters/flat-mount-brake-caliper-to-140-post-mount-frame-fork-with-140-rotor/) a post mount to flat mount adapter for 140mm rotor.

Comment: https://www.assolutions.ca/shop/adapters/flat-mount-brake-caliper-to-140-post-mount-frame-fork-with-140-rotor/

Comment: This might just work, but Nathan will need a IS to PM adapter too. A PM-to-FM has been asked about by a lot of people, good thing it's available for sale now.

Comment: I checkd and actually the make cool stuff, useful. Thanks for the tip again ;)